Первые найденные археологами - какая часть речи у "найденными"?
В предложении "Это были украшения, хлопковые ткани (первые найденные археологами)".
нужна ли запятая перед "найденные"? Я бы не ставила, в книге есть... Я бы не ставила по аналогии с "первые пришедшие" как прилагательное. А запятая стоит, видимо, как перед причастием.

Зависимое слово - археологами. Причастие.
Это были украшения, хлопковые ткани (первые, найденные археологами).

Смысл сообщения не вполне ясен, возможное редактирование:
Это были украшения, хлопковые ткани (первые предметы, найденные археологами).
Найденные археологами — причастный оборот, предметы — определяемое существительное.
